# Add websites to JRE8 Java Web Start exclusions list unattendedly (JRE8)

Tags: windows, command-line, browser, jre

In JRE8, applets on some sites don't start until exception added for these sites:

[image: Java Control Panel]

My question is, how to change these setting during or after silent install to allow browser applets from sites we use. Let's say these sites are https://1.example.com/ and https://2.example.org/

Note that in our company, we have both Chrome and Firefox installed for all users, and even IE is available for cases when other browsers are helpless (ActiveX on sites). So I need JRE to work in all three browsers (and yes, I know it will stop working in Chrome after a version or two because of deprecating NPAPI plugins, I need it to work just until then).

My current [`INSTALLCFG`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html):

```
INSTALL_SILENT=Enable
AUTO_UPDATE=Disable
WEB_JAVA=Enable
REBOOT=Disable
NOSTARTMENU=Enable
SPONSORS=Disable
```

WEB_JAVA enables Java in Browsers, but I still need to add exclusions.

Comment: You are not sure.  Simple enough to confirm if it is thus you can update your question, try it, if it works you have your answer.

Comment: Edited the question, but I still don't have the answer.